# get random input from bot and post it back

Tags: php

I'm currently making a chat bot with php.

The code I use reads a given message and responds with a new message if it matches a certain preset.

If a person sends the message "/repeat text" with *text* being a random input, the bot should echo "repeat>text" with the same text as in the input.

This is, what I've done so far.

```php
<?php
    if (strtolower($message['text']) == "/repeat text"){
        $client->replyMessage(array(
            'replyToken' => $event['replyToken'],
            'messages' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'text' => 'repeat>text'
                )
            )
        ));
    }
?>
```

edit for response:

```
<?php

if (strtolower($message['text']) == "hey"){
    $client->replyMessage(array(
        'replyToken' => $event['replyToken'],
        'messages' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'text' => 'hey person'
            )
        )
    ));
}

if (preg_match('/^\/repeat (.+)/g', strtolower($message['text']), $matches)){
    $client->replyMessage(array(
        'replyToken' => $event['replyToken'],
        'messages' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'text' => 'repeat>' . $matches[1]
            )
        )
    ));
}
?>
```

the top part works fine

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether your input message *is equal* to "/repeat text". You don't want to check for equality but whether it matches a certain expression. Therefore you can use **regular expressions**.

The most important function to you will be [`preg_match`](https://php.net/preg_match) that checks whether a string matches a certain pattern (in your case "/repeat" at the beginning).

Your final code could look like this:

```php
<?php
    if (preg_match('/^\/repeat (.+)/', strtolower($message['text']), $matches)) {
        $client->replyMessage([
            'replyToken' => $event['replyToken'],
            'messages' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'text' => 'repeat>' . $matches[1]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: i tried this and also tried it modified, see the main post for code

Comment: I wrote a little test scenario as I neither have your `$client` nor `$event`. Probably you don't need to include the regex modifier 'g'.

The full example that's working for me can be found here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c0afeb26139aeb28e22d87fd9e19dd5bd5f8b69

Comment: I tried to use your code but it didnt work. im currently trying to make a line bot from this source https://github.com/GoneTone/line-example-bot-php